# NetBeans file view?

Tags: netbeans

NetBeans seems to *really* like working with projects, but I don't want a stinkin' project, I just want to work with the files I've already got. I want to see all the files I've got in a directory in the sidebar. A tree view.

NetBeans does have a "Files" window, but that displays all the files in a project, not in a directory. Is there an add-on that does what I want?

I should also note that these are SVN checked out files. I'll need to commit them back. I know NetBeans has SVN support, but will it recognize the file is versioned if I open it directly? Doesn't seem to acknowledge that.

Answer (score 4):

There's a Window called "Favorites" that you can open from the Window menu. Inside that Window you have a context actions that lets you add any directory in your filesystem. It will then be displayed in a treeview. you will also have context menu Actions, like you have them in the Files view for "real" projects. 
Also there's a plugin called "Automatic Projects" that will open ANT based projects without screwing them up, importing, etc.

Answer (score 2):

As near as I can tell (I've only been using netbeans for about a month), projects are not much more than links to directories - once I "import" an existing project/directory I can browse freely from the imported directory root.

Might not be the answer you're looking for, but easy enough to import an existing directory of files to see if it works for you - just think of it as a named bookmark.

Comment: Well, it is working for me for now, but I don't see why I should have to clutter my filesystem with NetBeans projects just so I can access my files!